# Changing audio source by grabbing contents of a class with .html(), jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my Fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/omgwhyamisobad/zexf5o1n/

Basically, I want to change the source of my audio player when I click on a play button by grabbing the url inside of the `<div class="test2">`. I'm assuming I would use `.html()` to do this?

I've been working on this for a few hours now and can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to.

I've been able to get it to change the source if all the urls are the same, but not if they are different.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: Which `span` you want to pick?

Comment: I want to be able to click `<span class="artist-album-track-listing-mini-play">` and take the source from `<div class="test2">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("span.artist-album-track-listing-mini-play").click(function(){
        var allLyrics = $('.artist-album-indiv-info-right');
        var trackSource = $(this).next('.test2').html();
         allLyrics.hide();
        $('audio').attr('src', trackSource);
        $('#total_duration').text('00:00');
    });
});
```

Temporarily I have removed some part. You can add it if you want.

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zexf5o1n/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Then you should grab the source on `click` event, not outside. Use `text()` instead of `html()`.

*A little suggestion*: if you have more code to run on DOM ready, then instead of repeating `$(document).ready(single_method);` use : `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` and enclose the whole code here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var allLyrics = $('.artist-album-indiv-info-right');
    $('.artist-album-track-listing-mini-play').click(function () {
        var trackSource = $(this).parent().find('.test2').text(); 
        allLyrics.hide();
        $(this).closest('.artist-album-indiv-info-left').next('.artist-album-indiv-info-right').show();
        $('audio').attr('src', trackSource);
        $('#total_duration').text('00:00');
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zexf5o1n/3/)

Comment: `$(document).ready(lyricsAndTrack)` is correct way to call method on document ready, even it could be shortened using: `$(lyricsAndTrack);`

Comment: I know. But why repeat this every time we want to call a function when DOM is ready (supposed that there's more code on the page - If not, then it doesn't matter) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand what you mean by: `But why repeat this every time we want to call a function when DOM is ready` ?! If you meant it is quite useless regarding OP posted code, i'd say yes you are right because OP doesn't seem to recall same method later

Comment: I meant why not enclose whole code in single `document ready` closure, but split it like this: `$(document).ready(lyricsAndTrack);` , `$(document).ready(doAnotherStuff);`, `$(document).ready(doSomethingElse);`

Comment: That's ok, i see what you mean ;)